# Snapsvg – Move element via Drag and Arrow Keys

Tags: javascript, svg

How can I make an element draggable and movable with arrow keys in snapsvg? Currently it does not work correctly. It sometimes jumps back to the origin. Here is an example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tFGng

```
var s = Snap("#svg");

var orig = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};

var block = s.rect(0, 0, 6, 6);
block.attr({
    fill: "rgb(0, 0, 0)"
});

block.drag(


function (dx, dy, x, y, e) {
    var xSnap = Snap.snapTo(10, orig.x + dx + 3, 10);
    var ySnap = Snap.snapTo(10, orig.y + dy + 3, 10);

    this.attr({
        x: xSnap,
        y: ySnap
    });
},

function (x, y, e) {
    orig.x = e.toElement.x.baseVal.value;
    orig.y = e.toElement.y.baseVal.value;
    //origTransform = this.transform().local;
},

function (e) {
    console.log('on end');

    orig.x = e.toElement.x.baseVal.value;
    orig.y = e.toElement.y.baseVal.value;
}

);


$(document).on('keydown', function(event){
    var key = event.which;

    if( key === 37 || key === 38 || key === 39 || key === 40 ){
        event.preventDefault();
    }


    if( event.which === 37){
        //left
        orig.x -= 10;
    }

    if( event.which === 38){

        //up
        orig.y -= 10;

    }

    if( event.which === 39){
        //right

        orig.x += 10;
    }

    if( event.which === 40){
        //down

        orig.y += 10;
    }

    block.attr({
        x: orig.x,
        y: orig.y
    });

});
```

Comment: please add code of what you have tried so far

Comment: @gang Do you have a way to reproduce the jumping?

Comment: Just try out the codepen. Drag the small rectangle. After dragging, orig.x and orig.y are not saved and then when you use the arrow keys, the rectangle jumps back to its initial position.